# what should be the timestamp of first data merchant gateway?

Tags: php, integration, gateway, firstdata

i am integrating First Data Merchant Gateway into my website. I've generated the hash value of my price with current timestamp. Now the problem i am having is after sometime i think the hash value of price expire and  gateway page giving me the error.

> > Unable to proceed with payment

```
We cannot proceed with payment because of technical difficulties.    
Please try again later or contact customer support at Exomind LLC.
```

and my form is like

```
        <input name="x_login" value="WSP-EXO-X-XXXXXXXXXX" type="hidden">
        <input name="x_amount" value="99.99" type="hidden">
        <input name="x_fp_sequence" value="142352009847534" type="hidden"> 
        <input name="x_fp_timestamp" value="1414699123" type="hidden"> 
        <input name="x_fp_hash" value="fff641981dbe76e74f243f04bbe3c630" type="hidden">
        <input name="x_currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
        <input name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM" type="hidden">
        <input name="x_relay_response" value="TRUE" type="hidden">

        <input type = "image" src ="//content.authorize.net/images/buy-now-blue.gif" />
```

please tell me what i am missing.

Comment: Sorry, timestamp does not care about the timezones, it is already in GMT/UTC. Did you try to contact customer support, may be the reason is not in timestamp? Also, there is a example for different languages https://firstdata.zendesk.com/entries/452518-Generating-the-Payment-Request-Form-Programmatically

Comment: i already posted a question on there website & now i am waiting for their reply.